# Add polygon areas by roof orientation condition

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, area, aggregation

I have a shapefile with building poligons and a raster file with the roof orientation (0-360º). I would like to assign the orientation to the building shapefile using QGIS. I converted the raster file to vector.
My strategy rely on adding columns to the building shapefile assigning the 4 main orientations (N,W,S,E) areas.

One example. "dataframe.shp":

[image] [image]

and vector file of the orientation (with the attribute table presenting the orientation values in º) '"orientation.shp"' :

[image]
[image]

With this, what I would like to obtain is 4 columns with the area for each main orientation for each building polygon.

Example of rational -> using field calculator for the south orientaion column:

```
CASE
    WHEN  "DN">135 and "DN"<225  THEN (SUM AREA OF each polgon within this range inside building polygon)
    Else 0
END
```

I dont know how to complete the conditional and assign it to each building polygon ('dataframe.shp').
Also, I am afraid that is infesiable for a large dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sum()` with a filter, like this:

```
sum(area($geometry),filter:="DN">135 and "DN"<225 and intersects($geometry,get_feature('buildingpolygon',"buildingid",'thisbuildingid'))
```

Maybe even simpler if you add the building ids first via an intersection operation and then just use this in an group_by parameter, like:

```
sum(area($geometry),group_by:="buildingid",filter:="DN">135 and "DN"<225)
```

Comment: TY. But with this option I cannot perform the operation for all building polygons, right? Because I am refering to the building id. Also, I performe this in the "Field Calculator" for which layer?

Comment: Perform this in the layer 'orientation'. You can calculate it for all buildings at once because the group by statement ensures the correct sum is added to the correct feature.

Comment: Ok. So I did this: sum("DN",group_by:="Name",filter:="DN">135 and "DN"<225) after the intersection with the dataframe. But the sum value that I get it is not the sum of the areas of the "orientation" layer polygons (ex pixels from raster). It seems the sum of the degree values. As I would like to have this info in the "dataframe" layer I would need to perform the "join by location" again ...?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Use `area($geometry)` or `$area` in the sum, just corrected the answer.

Comment: TY. Worked fine. I had to perform again a join location to consider the data on the dataframe.